# Преобразование файла из doc в pdf

Tags: php, phpword, dompdf

Заполняю договор с помощью PhpWord потом преобразую его в pdf с помощью Dompdf. На выходе создаётся pdf документ размером 0 кб. Может кто-то сталкивался с подобным?

```
<?php
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
require_once  'dompdf/autoload.inc.php' ;
$document = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\TemplateProcessor('./dogovor.docx');

$uploadDir =  __DIR__;
$outputFile = 'dorovor_full.docx';

$birth = $_POST['birth'];
$name = $_POST['name'];
$adres = $_POST['adres'];

$document->setValue('name', $name);
$document->setValue('birth', $birth);
$document->setValue('adres', $adres);

$document->saveAs($outputFile);
// Имя скачиваемого файла
$downloadFile = $outputFile;

// Контент-тип означающий скачивание
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");

// Размер в байтах
header("Accept-Ranges: bytes");

// Размер файла
header("Content-Length: ".filesize($downloadFile));

// Расположение скачиваемого файла
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$downloadFile);  

// Прочитать файл
readfile($downloadFile);

$path = realpath(realpath(__DIR__) . '/dompdf');
 
\PhpOffice\PhpWord\Settings::setPdfRendererPath($path);
\PhpOffice\PhpWord\Settings::setPdfRendererName(\PhpOffice\PhpWord\Settings::PDF_RENDERER_DOMPDF);

$phpWord = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::load($outputFile); 
$xmlWriter = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::createWriter($phpWord , 'PDF');
$xmlWriter->save('result.pdf', 'PDF');
unlink($outputFile);
?>
```

Comment: `echo "realpath: " . $path;` и зачем вы это выводите? Хотите испортить файл? Где код вывода содержимого pdf файла?

Comment: @ArchDemon все заработало только вместо букв знаки вопроса

Comment: Кодировка и шрифты. Проблема в этом