# При конвертации из docx в pdf получается пустой файл

Tags: php, phpword, dompdf

На виртуальном хостинге "Smartape" пытаюсь конвертировать файл .docx в .pdf

С помощью Composer установил [PHPOffice/PHPWord](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord), [dompdf](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf) и все, что требовалось к нему: [php-font-lib](https://github.com/dompdf/php-font-lib), [html5lib](https://github.com/Masterminds/html5-php), [php-svg-lib](https://github.com/dompdf/php-svg-lib).

В разделе "[Quick Start](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf?tab=readme-ov-file#quick-start)" у dompdf есть пример скрипта:

```
    // reference the Dompdf namespace
use Dompdf\Dompdf;

// instantiate and use the dompdf class
$dompdf = new Dompdf();
$dompdf->loadHtml('hello world');

// (Optional) Setup the paper size and orientation
$dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'landscape');

// Render the HTML as PDF
$dompdf->render();

// Output the generated PDF to Browser
$dompdf->stream();
```

Выполнив этот скрипт получаю пустой PDF файл.
Во время поиска в интернете ( в т.ч. и на [stackoverflow](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1270408/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%B7-doc-%D0%B2-pdf)) выяснил, что этим вопросом задаются многие, но никто не получил на него внятный ответ.
Прошу у участников сообщества помощи. Может кто уже решил этот вопрос?